# Eagle libraries for Automotive Header connectors

Tags: eaglecad

I am working on a diagnostic tool for automotive application that will be able to check wire integrity and offer a very quick way for technicians to know if there are any physical wiring faults while beginning an electrical diagnostic.

The connectors I will be interfacing with are fairly complex (never less than 100 pins) and are sold in bulk, however I have had zero luck finding any Eagle libraries for any of them, despite combing through Google, Eagle dev, and calls to TE, AMP, and a bunch of vendors. All of the connectors whose Eagle files I need even have the same "node", Automotive Headers. Anybody have tips for where I could look for these pretty niche, but still high volume connectors?

Comment: Why don't you create your own?

Answer (score 2):

You can't expect a CAD system to have schematic symbols and footprints for all possible components you might use.

If you can't find the part you want quickly, you should just make it yourself.  If you do this, you will be sure that the symbol matches the actual part you are going to use (I like to have the actual part in my hand when making symbols and footprints.)

As I have found errors in commercial libraries, I always check the actual part, or maker's datasheet) against the symbols I will use - this often takes almost as long as making the symbols myself.